# Second K-1 Visa

Tags: usa, immigration, greencard, k1-visa

Eight years ago, I requested a K-1 Visa for my fiancee and was approved. I married that woman and we remained married for seven years. We divorced in the middle of last year and she went back to her country.

Since then, an aunt introduced me to a different woman whom I've discovered to be my true soul mate and love of my life. I proposed to her at the start of this year and want to marry before the end of the year. I've already started gathering documents and proof for the K-1 Visa, including my divorce decree. We've already met twice in person (I went once, then she came to visit me). I have tons of proof and photos of our relationship. We literally talk on the phone every single day for hours.

My question is, will I have any trouble getting the K-1 Visa approved since this will be the second one I request? Albeit, my first one was eight years ago, but I was just wondering if there is a limit or something. My fiancee is from the same country as my ex-wife (Nicaragua).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can petition for two K1 visas in your lifetime without any need for special consideration as long as two years have passed since the first K1 petition. It's after two such petitions that you will need a waiver for all subsequent K1 petitions. [Petition for Alien Fiance - Item Numbers 5.a. - 5.d.](https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/i-129finstr.pdf?download=1)

So no, as it appears your first marriage was genuine, and sufficient time has passed since the first application, you shouldn't have any problems, assuming you and your fiance meet all of the other qualifications.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you so much for removing any doubts.